# NodeJS eventloop execution order

Tags: node.js, events

When sending several requests serially, it seems like

- callbacks are executed when all requests are sent.
- requests seems to get added into a queue but not actually getting executed before the loop is done.

**Example**

```
var http = require('http');

var i=0;
var postData = [];

while (i++ < 12) {
    var largeObject = [
        'this' + i,
        'that' + i,
        'then' + i
    ];

    postData.push(largeObject);

    if (postData.length >= 2) {
        console.log('request');
        var options = {
            hostname: 'httpbin.org',
            port: 80,
            path: '/post',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        };
        var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
            console.log(res.statusCode);
            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                console.log(chunk.toString());
            });

            res.on('end', function() {
                console.log('finished reading response');
            });
        });
        req.end(JSON.stringify(postData), function() {
            console.log('request stream finished');
        });

        postData = [];
    }
}
```

The output here would look like

```
request
request
request
request
request
request
request stream finished
request stream finished
request stream finished
request stream finished
request stream finished
request stream finished
200
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "[[\"this7\",\"that7\",\"then7\"],[\"this8\",\"that8\",\"then8\"]]", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "53", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org"
  }, 
  "json": [
    [
      "this7", 
      "that7", 
      "then7"
    ], 
    [
      "this8", 
      "that8", 
      "then8"
    ]
  ], 
  "origin": "xxxxx", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}

finished reading response
200
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "[[\"this1\",\"that1\",\"then1\"],[\"this2\",\"that2\",\"then2\"]]", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "53", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org"
  }, 
  "json": [
    [
      "this1", 
      "that1", 
      "then1"
    ], 
    [
      "this2", 
      "that2", 
      "then2"
    ]
  ], 
  "origin": "xxxx", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
...
```

Is there any way to finish one request before the next one is getting executed?

I don't really care about the order, it's more about memory - I'd like to get rid of large objects I am posting

e.g.

```
request1
response1
request2
response2
request3
response3
request4
request5
response5
response4
```

would be absolutely fine.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, just use some control-flow modules like async or bluebird.

As you don't care about order, I'd advise you to use either [async#parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) or [bluebird#map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html). The `bluebird#map` has a concurrency argument, which can be nice when you need some more control over loops and their amount (so does `async#parallelLimit`).

If this doesn't seem straightforward, please comment and I'll add an example.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Maybe the question wasn't clear enough.

In my real code, I am preparing a large object in each loop cycle and I'd like to submit and clear it from memory as soon as possible.

I have updated above example to better reflect what I am doing.

I don't see how `async.parallel` for example would help me with that.
An example would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by "submit" the object? Async.parallel for example would allow you to call a function when each request is done, and then you'll have the last callback when everything is done. IMO you can implement what you need with a simple [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html).